# Trying to check to see if something exists and if not, assign something different to it with JavaScript

Tags: node.js, discord

Wondering if someone can help, I'll try to explain the best I can. I am looking at a json file for various steam games. Basically what I want to do is check to see if a certain "key(?)" is present and if not then return "None".

e.g. Check to see if `body[id].data.metacritic` and if it does then assign `score` to `body[id].data.metacritic.score`. The same with URL. I cannot figure this out!

I have tried the following:

```
        if(bulk.metacritic) var { score, url } = bulk.metacritic[0] || "None";
```

I just can't figure out how to get this right! Basically, `body[id].data.metacritic` doesn't exist in all json files, along with other parameters so I just want to display some placeholder text if they don't appear.

Comment: You could check if `body[id].data.metacritic == undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `body[id].data.metacritic` is an array with a non-zero length and if so, use a value from it, otherwise use default values:

```
let score, url;
let data = body[id].data;
if (data && Array.isArray(data.metacritic) && data.metacritic.length > 0) {
    score = data.metacritic[0].score;
    url = data.metacritic[0].url;
} else {
    score = url = "None";
}

console.log(score, url);
```